# Application of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem: Confusion on how to exclude a case

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have been exposed to the following version of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

> **Theorem (Stone-Weierstrass):** Let $K$ be compact and let $\mathbb{A}$  be a subalgebra of $C_\mathbb{C}(K)$, separating the points of $K$. Assume that for all $f \in \mathbb{A}$ we have $\bar{f} \in \mathbb{A}$. Then we have either:
>
> 1)  $\overline{\mathbb{A}} = C_\mathbb{C}(K) $ or
>   2) $\exists !$ $x_0 \in K$ such that $\overline{\mathbb{A}} =  \lbrace f \in C_\mathbb{C}(K) : f(x_0)=0 \rbrace$

---

There is an example in my notes and I don't manage to verify the crucial step which allows me to exclude a case.

**Example:** Let $S^1 = \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| =1 \rbrace$ and let $M$ be the set given by $$ M:= \lbrace f: S^1 \to \mathbb{C} \mid f(z) = \sum_{ |k| \leq n } c_k z^k, \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \ c_k \in \mathbb{C} \rbrace$$

The claim is then that $\overline{M} = C_\mathbb{C}(S^1)$. I tried verify this statement but I got stuck at excluding the case denoted as 2) in the above theorem.

**Proof:** Indeed $K= S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact and $\mathbb{A}=M \subset C_{\mathbb{C}}(K)$ is a subalgebra separating the points of $K$.

Evidently $M$ is a (linear) subspace of $C_{\mathbb{C}}(K)$ that is closed under multiplication, i.e. if $f,g \in M$ then also $f\cdot g \in M$ because we're dealing with polynomial expressions. Further we have if $f \in M$ then so is $\bar{f} \in M$.

Further $M$ separates the points of $S^1$, because if we take $x, y \in S^1$ such that $x \neq y$ then we can simply set $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{C}, \ z \mapsto z$ then indeed $f \in M$ ($n = 0, c_0=0, c_1=1$) and we have $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Thus $\mathbb{A}=M$ is as claimed a subalgebra of $C_\mathbb{C}(S^1)$ separating the points of $S^1$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem I get $\overline{M} = C_\mathbb{C}(S^1)$ (in which case I would be done) or I get the existence of a unique point $x_0 \in S^1$ such that $\overline{M} = \lbrace f \in C_\mathbb{C}(S^1): f(x_0)=0 \rbrace$

**My Question:** How do I exclude the 2nd case?

I found several references that this might have something to do with the sigma algebra being "unital", i.e. $1 \in M$, but I can't see how this relates to the 2nd case.

Comment: We indeed have $1\in M$ and thus $1\in \overline{M}$, Now, if we were in the second case, we would have this $x_0\in K$ with the property $0 = 1(x_0) = 1$, which is a contradiction. So we can't be in the second case.

Comment: You are right, it's that simple. Thank you.